# GGplot Barplot does not accept Y value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataframe:

```
>picard
count    reads
 1    20681318
 2     3206677
 3      674351
 4      319173
 5      139411
 6      117706
```

How do I plot  log10(count) vs log10(reads)  on a ggplot (barplot)?

I tried:

```
ggplot(picard) + geom_bar(aes(x=log10(count),y=log10(reads)))
```

But it is not accepting y=log10(reads). How do I plot my y values?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do something like this, but plotting the x axis, which is not continuous, with a log10 scale doesn't make sense for me :

```
ggplot(picard) +
    geom_bar(aes(x=count,y=reads),stat="identity") +
    scale_y_log10() +
    scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

If you only want an y axis with a log10 scale, just do :

```
ggplot(picard) +
    geom_bar(aes(x=count,y=reads),stat="identity") +
    scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to increase the width of the bars?

Comment: @user2703967 Yes, use the `width` argument of `geom_bar()`.

Comment: The graph is very staggered because of the data. Can I use a geom_density() to plot these values? I would probably need to set my own density but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: @user2703967, Please think carefully about what you really wish to achieve before people start spending their time trying to help you. A density plot is quite different from a bar plot.

Comment: The thing is, because the data is so varied, the barplot is very staggered. Which is why I want to plot a density plot so that it gives me a smooth line but essentially the shape would be same as the barplot.

Answer (score 6):

Use `stat="identity"`:

```
ggplot(picard) + geom_bar(aes(x=log10(count),y=log10(reads)), stat="identity")
```

You will actually get a warning with your approach:

> Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".
>     With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.
>     This can result in unexpected behavior and will not be allowed in a future version of ggplot2.
>     If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y.
>     If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".
>     See ?geom_bar for examples. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.2)

Answer (score 2):

There's a direct way to do this, i.e. by using the geom_col() function. Just make a tiny adjustment to your code:

```
ggplot(picard) + geom_col(aes(x=log10(count), y=log10(reads)))
```

and it will give the same output as setting the `stat` argument to `identity` with `geom_bar()`. The thing is, `geom_bar()` uses `count` as default for stat, hence it will not take any variable for the y-axis. It will simply use the count, i.e, the number of occurrences of each value of the x-axis, for it's y-axis. I hope this answers your question.