# In R how can I make a six-bar chart where each bar contains a range of data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a spreadsheet that shows the ages and games played for baseball players.

```
structure(list(Player = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), Games = c(21, 7, 159, 156, 10, 152, 
23, 68, 13, 123, 29, 13, 111, 2, 84, 15, 140, 93), Age = c(34, 
23, 33, 22, 28, 24, 28, 33, 33, 29, 29, 25, 20, 41, 37, 21, 22, 
31), under21 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Y21to25 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0), Y26to30 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Y31to35 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Y36to40 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), over40 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is another view of it using glimpse(df). I added the six columns from "under21" thru "over40" for illustrative purposes.

```
Observations: 18
Variables: 9
$ Player  <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
$ Games   <dbl> 21, 7, 159, 156, 10, 152, 23, 68, 13, 123, 29, 13, 111, 2, 84…
$ Age     <dbl> 34, 23, 33, 22, 28, 24, 28, 33, 33, 29, 29, 25, 20, 41, 37, 2…
$ under21 <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ Y21to25 <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
$ Y26to30 <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ Y31to35 <dbl> 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
$ Y36to40 <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
$ over40  <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

What I need is a bar chart with six bars ("under21" thru "over40") rising from the x-axis. The y-axis, "Games," will show the number of games played by all the players in each age group. So, the "under21" bar will show the total games played by all the players under age 21, and so on.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Player `13` has a value `1` in both `under21` and `Y36to40` groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe into a longer format using `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr` package (part of `tidyverse`), filter out 0 values and then plot the total of games in function of the category they belong using `geom_col`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(Player, Games, Age), names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels = c("under21","Y21to25","Y26to30","Y31to35","Y36to40","over40"))) 
  
# A tibble: 108 x 5
   Player Games   Age var       val
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
 1      1    21    34 under21     0
 2      1    21    34 Y21to25     0
 3      1    21    34 Y26to30     0
 4      1    21    34 Y31to35     1
 5      1    21    34 Y36to40     0
 6      1    21    34 over40      0
 7      2     7    23 under21     0
 8      2     7    23 Y21to25     1
 9      2     7    23 Y26to30     0
10      2     7    23 Y31to35     0
# … with 98 more rows
```

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(Player, Games, Age), names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels = c("under21","Y21to25","Y26to30","Y31to35","Y36to40","over40"))) %>%
  filter(val != 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var, y = Games, fill = var))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to achieve ?

---

**EDIT: Calculating sum of Games outside `ggplot2`**

You can calculate yourself the sum of Games per categordy by doing:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(Player, Games, Age), names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels = c("under21","Y21to25","Y26to30","Y31to35","Y36to40","over40"))) %>%
  filter(val != 0) %>%
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(Games = sum(Games)) 

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  var     Games
  <fct>   <dbl>
1 under21   111
2 Y21to25   483
3 Y26to30   185
4 Y31to35   354
5 Y36to40   195
6 over40      2
```

And you can add pipe sequence to plot it directly by doing:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gpglot2)
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(Player, Games, Age), names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels = c("under21","Y21to25","Y26to30","Y31to35","Y36to40","over40"))) %>%
  filter(val != 0) %>%
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(Games = sum(Games)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var, y = Games, fill = var))+
  geom_col()
```

And you will get the exact same plot

Comment: Does the "var" object contain both the column names and their data (zeros and ones) for "under21" to "over40"? (Does "names_to" transfer both?) Given that "fill = var," how is it that the bars show Games data sums?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how looks like the dataframe just before plotting. Var contain categories names that you will use a x-axis. As we put `y = Games`, `geom_col` will sum the `y` in function of `x`, so here, the sum of Games in function of categories. `fill = var` is just for adding some colors to the bar. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm sure sure of the meaning of "so here, the sum of Games in function of categories."

Comment: Just calculate yourself the sum of Games for each category and you will see that it is the number displayed by `ggplot2`. Basically, for each category, it makes the sum of Games.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you an alternative where you calculte the total of games per category outside of `ggplot2`. You get the exact same plot. Does it make more sense now ?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT -- `reshape2` has been superseded by `tidyr`. Please refer to [dc37's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60402057/7976890) for a more up-to-date approach.

---

This solution uses `melt` from the `reshape2` package to collapse the age variables into two columns: `variable` and `value`.  From there, you can subset your data frame to include only rows where `value` is `1`, and then create your bar graph, specifying `stat = "identity"` to let `geom_bar` know that you are [supplying your own y value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19389888/7976890).

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

stats <- structure(list(Player = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), Games = c(21, 7, 159, 156, 10, 152, 
23, 68, 13, 123, 29, 13, 111, 2, 84, 15, 140, 93), Age = c(34, 
23, 33, 22, 28, 24, 28, 33, 33, 29, 29, 25, 20, 41, 37, 21, 22, 
31), under21 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Y21to25 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0), Y26to30 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Y31to35 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Y36to40 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), over40 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame")

stats <- melt(stats, id.vars = c("Player","Games","Age"))
stats <- stats[stats$value == 1,]

p <-  ggplot(stats, aes(x = variable, y = Games))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + xlab("")
```

[image]

This code does not account for Player `13` appearing in both `under21` and `Y36to40` groups.

Comment: BTW, `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` is actually the same than `geom_col()` because `geom_col` use by default `stat = "identity"` : https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html. But both are correct.

Comment: @Dirigible, I found it interesting that Games was one of the id.vars and not a measure variable.Why is that? Also, thanks for catching the fact that Player 13 is in two groups.